# Can I tell javac to ignore the lack of `import foo.Bar`?

Tags: java, import, compilation, javac, compiler-optimization

I'm using reflection to load `MyClass.class` (an external file) at runtime.

`MyClass.class` uses the library `Bar`, which would mean that I need to place `import foo.Bar;` at the top of the file.

However, the `Bar` library is already loaded in the main class loading `MyClass`.

Is there a way for me to tell javac to ignore that `Bar` doesn't exist and just compile without it?

Comment: I feel you might be withholding an important aspect of your question: MyClass.class already exists, so that's not what you are compiling. Where, then, do you need to put the `import foo.Bar` declaration? Do you have a class of your own code that explicitly references `MyClass` (not via reflection)? Is your class flagged because it indirectly needs Bar which the compiler doesn't find? So: where exactly does the compiler complain and what exactly does it say?

Answer (score 6):

No this is not possible. When compiling a class, the compiler has no "memory" of which classes were already "loaded" (don't confuse this with the concept related to classloading -- that's a completely different story). Whenever a class is compiled and a reference to a class is found that is not in the same package, an `import` statement is required.

This being said, it seems there is a contradiction in your question: from what you say, `MyClass` is already compiled because the file `MyClass.class` exists, so there is no compiler being involved here. It's the classloader that does the loading. In this case, as far as the classloader is concerned, if `Bar` was already referenced in the main class, then it won't be loaded again from within `MyClass`.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such option in javac command.